# Cordova project Build time show Error -- Build Failed

Tags: java, android, node.js, cordova

When try to build cordova project in cmd with
android 6.4.0 also try android 7.1.0 but still showing **build failed**
Below Error Show after build cordova project 
cordova build android

> ANDROID_HOME=G:\shripati\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x
>   86_64-20140702\sdk JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172
>   Subproject Path: CordovaLib Observed package id 'build-tools;20.0.0'
>   in inconsistent location 'G:\shripati\a
>   dt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\build-t
>   ools\android-4.4W' (Expected
>   'G:\shripati\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt
>   -bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\20.0.0')
>
> FAILED BUILD FAILED Total time: 50.818 secs FAILURE: Build failed with
>   an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task
>   ':processDebugResources'.
>
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute
>   aapt * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run
>   with --info or --debug option to get more log output. (node:6448)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command failed with ex
>   it code 1 Error output: Note: Some input files use or override a
>   deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note:
>   Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. ERROR: In
>   FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:f ont ERROR: In
>   FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:f ontStyle ERROR: In
>   FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:f
>   ontVariationSettings ERROR: In FontFamilyFont, unable to find
>   attribute android:f ontWeight ERROR: In FontFamilyFont, unable to find
>   attribute android:t tcIndex FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. *
>   What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute
>   aapt * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run
>   with --info or --debug option to get more log output. at
>   ChildProcess.whenDone
>   (D:\shri\convertVisualStudio\shri\LBSCRM\platforms\
>   android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
>   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13) at maybeClose
>   (internal/child_process.js:957:16) at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:5)
>   (node:6448) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:6448) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depre cated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 0):

These resources were only added in the android-P preview, so if you want to use a library that references them you need to update your compile sdk to android-P preview, you can follow [this guide](https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk).

Comment: But yesterday same project build successfully

Comment: i done this but still same error display
Observed package id 'build-tools;28.0.0-rc2' in inconsistent location '28.0.0-preview' (Expected 'G:\shripati\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-201407
02\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\28.0.0-rc2')
Observed package id 'build-tools;20.0.0' in inconsistent location 'build-t
ools\android-4.4W' (Expected 'sdk\build-tools\20.0.0')

Comment: How did you get these build tools? You should be using the ones from sdk/build-tools as the message is saying.

Comment: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

Comment: Another project working properly with same android But this one showing Error

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. You probably have some dependency with version using the "+" sign to pick up the newest available one. The new one was probably published in the last few days and so that's why it got picked up.

Comment: Installed platforms:
  android 6.3.0
  ios 4.3.1
this platform we use... and after cordova build it's show 
**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt**
Error

Comment: but i did't understand which dependency is updated so i can to install older one